# Tefillin smell after the paint has dried

Tags: tefilin

When i paint my tefillin batim with the paint. It has a certain type of smell. I just want to know how to get rid of the smell as it doesn't smell like natural leather as tefillin should smell like.

Comment: Maybe wearing them daily will help take away the scent eventually? I don't know though. My tefillin never smelled like leather, at least not in the same way a leather jacket, etc. smells. Tefillin have their own smell, and it's usually the paint that gives them that scent.

Comment: The smells feel artificial like I'm smelling something machine-like/ chemical-induced.

Comment: I suggest you leave them out of their boxes in a room with an open window for several hours.

Comment: it worked. Thank you Yitzchok.